# Как заставить приложение ссылаться на свой фреймворк? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, framework

Предположим следующую ситуацию: пользователь скачивает приложение на фреймворке .NET 4.7.2, а на его компьютере установлен только .NET 4.5 и соответственно приложение не запускается, выдавая ошибку. Можно ли в проект установить фреймворк определенной версии и заставить проект постоянно ссылаться на него? Возможно, что приложение и будет весить больше, но особо не важно. Желательно разжевать ответ для чайника+.

Comment: Можно, надо лишь вам обновиться до современного .NET, а не использовать устаревший .NET Framework... Как перейдете, в настройках публикации будет нужная галка, которая встроит вам сам .NET в .exe.

Comment: Используйте .NET 6